# jquery ui dialog not closing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am new to jQuery UI. I wrote the following code as a part of ASP.NET MVC project, and I am not sure why the dialog isn't getting closed. I tried so many things but it just seems to be not working. Can anyone help?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(function () {

    $("#flightModal").dialog({
        title: 'Flight Quotations',
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 700,
        height: 450,
        modal: false,
        draggable: true,
        context: $(this),
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
            $(this).load(url);
        },
        buttons: {
            "Cancel": function () {
                $("#flightModal").dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

$("#createFlight").on("click", function (e) {
    url = "/Quotations/QuotationsFlight"
    $("#flightModal").dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

});
});

I tried destroy, remove and all other solutions described in other stackoverflow questions. I believe I am missing a simple thing, but couldn't figure it out so far.

Comment: It works here - http://jsfiddle.net/o3vxj2da/

Comment: Do you get any script errors in the console? There may be an error somewhere else that breaks jQuery. (These will drive you nuts)

Comment: This is what I see in console: http://i.imgur.com/Xbak040.png

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(function () {
```

The below two lines are the same. Try to remove the following layout. It should work.

```
$(function () {
});
```

Something like this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#flightModal").dialog({
        title: 'Flight Quotations',
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 700,
        height: 450,
        modal: false,
        draggable: true,
        context: $(this),
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
            $(this).load(url);
        },
        buttons: {
            "Cancel": function () {
                $("#flightModal").dialog('close');
            }
        }

    $("#createFlight").on("click", function (e) {
        url = "/Quotations/QuotationsFlight"
        $("#flightModal").dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried this, but it didn't work. I strongly feel there is something wrong with the way I am including jQuery UI and jQuery. As I said, I am using this code in MVC Razor and I tried the same thing in plan HTML/JS and it works perfectly, here is the code: http://codepen.io/chandu_vrs/pen/NPzNxR